# php mysql check db first

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$thesite = strip_tags($_GET['s']);

$original_file = @file_get_contents($thesite);
if ($original_file  === false) {
    die("$thesite does not exist");
} elseif($orginial_file === true ) {
    $data = $path_info['host'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM first WHERE name='$data'");
} else {
    //step3
}
```

I want to check the DB for `$data`. If it exists, move on to the next step; if not, do step 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
```

$thesite = strip_tags($_GET['s']);

```
$original_file = @file_get_contents($thesite);
if ($original_file  === false) {
    die("$thesite does not exist");
} elseif($orginial_file === true ) {
    $data = $path_info['host'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM first WHERE name='$data'");
    #exist = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if ($exist) {
        // next step
    }
    else {
        // step 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `mysql_num_rows` after running the query. If it's `0`, there were no rows with `name` equal to `$data`.

By the way, you shouldn't be inserting `$data` directly into your query, otherwise you're open to SQL injection. Here's a better way:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM first WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."'");
```

Also, `file_get_contents` will not return `true` if it succeeds. It will return the contents of the file as a string.

Comment: Also `$original_file` will be either false or the content of the file, not the `true` so you can use the `=== true` in your if.